# Enqueue Javascript in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I am enqueuing javascript files with functions.php, one of the is a external link and another is not.

They are both loading all right, but it's loading the internal file before the external, so there're some bits of the code that are not working.

This is the code:

```
function _tandt_scripts() {
  $my_js_ver  = date("ymd-Gis");

  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', array(), '2.1.3', true);

  wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_assets/js/main/min/main-min.js', array(), $my_js_ver, true );

  if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_tandt_scripts' );
```

As you can see in the screenshot, it's loading the 'main-min.js' first, when it should be the other way around.

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: because you didn't enqueue jquery, you just registered it.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer. You can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re-registered the jQuery script but you didn't enqueue it to the page.

Add this line after `wp_register_script`:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

and change this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main', get_template_directory_uri() .
    '/_assets/js/main/min/main-min.js', array(), $my_js_ver, true );
```

to:

```
wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/_assets/js/main/min/main-min.js', array("jquery"), $my_js_ver, true );
```

to have `jquery` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified that the second script is dependent on the first.

```
wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/_assets/js/main/min/main-min.js',
    array(), $my_js_ver, true );
```

This line should be changed to include the `jquery` dependemcy.

```
wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/_assets/js/main/min/main-min.js',
    array('jquery'), $my_js_ver, true );
```

See the WordPress documentation for further details: [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)